# Xamarin iOS Launch Image Not Showing

Tags: xamarin, splash-screen

I am trying to use a LaunchScreen.storyboard to show a simple image.

I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos)

The image that I am trying to use doesn't show up.

I have another image in my assets.xcassets file that when I set the exact same ImageView to that one it shows up fine.

If I copy the image I want over the top of the image that works in its own folder under Assets.xcassets folder then the image I want works.

I just can't get the image I want located in its own Assets.xcassets folder to work as a splash screen.

If I add an  to any of my xaml forms then the image shows up fine.

The image also shows up fine in the storyboard editor in VS2019.

I am totally confused about why this image doesn't work as a splash on a LaunchScreen.storyboard.

I am hoping someone can help me figure it out.

This is a screenshot of my storyboard:
[image]

When I run the app I don't get anything other than a black splash screen.

Here is a screen shot of the exact same storyboard where I have changed the Image setting to another image in my Assets.xcassets.

[image]

When I have it set to that one the splash shows that image just fine on startup.

Here is an image of my Assets.xcassets folders:

[image]

[image]

As I said before if I simply copy and paste the image that doesn't work over the top of the one that does inside the Assets.xcassets folder (renaming it of course), then the image I want works fine as the splash.

So it is not the image itself. I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Hi, *I just can't get the image I want located in its own Assets.xcassets folder to work as a splash screen.* Could you share some screenshots to explain its meaning? It will be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: I added some screenshots. Hope this helps.

Comment: I just discovered some new information. I have been running this on the simulator of a iOS 11 Pro Max device. I just tried it on my iOS XS Max device and the splash shows up. I am still confused about why it doesn't work in the simulator. The resolutions are similar and that other image works fine and it almost exactly the same size.

Comment: Hi, do you mean it works in physical device? You also could have a try with testing other simulators to check whehter it works.

Comment: Figured out the difference, but don't know why it is happening. The Simulator is iOS 14. My physical device is iOS 13.7. I installed the 3.5 Simulator and ran my app on it and the splash shows up fine. So it has something to do with iOS 14 or the simulator version of it. Can you explain?

Comment: It's strange. I have tested with my local image, and it shows a black screen when launching in iOS 14 simulator. However, it shows correctly in native iOS application. Could you share version of VS ? If it's an issue, you could submit it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues) in Github.

Comment: I recently found a post on Apple's support site that this has something to do with iOS 14 and splash images. Don't know the details, but looks like an Apple thing.

Comment: Okey, if there is a similar issue, you could share that link here.

Comment: I don't have just one link. There are a lot of different links with different related problems and no real good solutions. If you just search for ios 14 splash screen black or something like that all kinds of stuff comes up. Sorry I am not more specific, but it really is a mix of possible causes and possible solutions that work for some, but not for others.

Comment: Okey, you also could submit it there if you have time, then there will be seen and be resolved more quickly.